# Android application to add rows dynamically in table layout giving error

Tags: android

Java code-

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONStringer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
public class DisplayStore extends Activity {
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";
// Creating JSON Parser object
//JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ContriList;
// url to get all products list
private static String url_get_contri =     "http://10.0.2.2/annapurna_connect/GetContri.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
/*  private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";*/
// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;
@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi" })
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_store);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
ContriList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url_get_contri,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
new LoadContri().execute();
}

/**
* Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
* */
class LoadContri extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
/**
* Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
* */
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "here i am",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayStore.this);
pDialog.setMessage("Loading Information. Please wait...");
pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
pDialog.show();
}
/**
* getting All products from url
* */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
// Building Parameters
try {

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
url_get_contri += "?" + paramString;
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url_get_contri);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
is = httpEntity.getContent();

}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
json = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}
/*catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}*/

// Log.d("checking",sb);    
// Check your log cat for JSON reponse
Log.d("All Products: ",json);
String category,type,city,state,abc;
String test="";
int serves;
try
{
//String json=sb.toString();
// String result=json_decode(json);
// String test="";
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json);
test+="here";
JSONObject json_data=null;
test+="here1";
TableLayout tv=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.Table);
tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
int flag=1;
test+="here2";

for(int i=-1;i<jArray.length();i++){

Log.d("i",String.valueOf(i));
TableRow tr=new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
test+="here4";
if(flag==1)
// this will be executed once
{
test+="here5";
TextView b3=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
b3.setText("Category");
b3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
b3.setTextSize(15);
tr.addView(b3);

TextView b4=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
b4.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
b4.setTextSize(15);
b4.setText("Type");
b4.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
tr.addView(b4);
test+="after1col";
TextView b5=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
b5.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
b5.setText("Serves");
b5.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
b5.setTextSize(15);
tr.addView(b5);

TextView b6=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
b6.setText("City");
b6.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
b6.setTextSize(15);
tr.addView(b6);
TextView b7=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
b7.setText("State");
b7.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
b7.setTextSize(15);
tr.addView(b7);
test+="heresettext";
tv.addView(tr);
test+="aftertv";
final View vline = new View(getApplicationContext());
test+="aftervline";
vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
test+="afterlayout";
vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
test+="aftersetback";
tv.addView(vline); // add line below heading
//tv.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
test+="addview";
flag=0;
test+="aftersettext";
Log.d("check","here");

}
else
{ Log.d("check","here");

test+="here6";
json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
test+="here7";

TextView b=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
category=String.valueOf(json_data.getString("Category"));
b.setText(category);
b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
b.setTextSize(15);
tr.addView(b);
TextView b1=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
b1.setTextSize(15);
type=json_data.getString("Type");
b1.setText(type);
b1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tr.addView(b1);
test+="after1col";

TextView b2=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
serves=json_data.getInt("Serves");
test+="getInt";
abc=String.valueOf(serves);
test+=abc;
b2.setText(abc);
test+="after2col";
b2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
b2.setTextSize(15);
tr.addView(b2);
TextView b3=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
b3.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
b3.setTextSize(15);
city=json_data.getString("City");
b3.setText(type);
b3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tr.addView(b3);
test+="after23col";
TextView b4=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
b4.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
b4.setTextSize(15);
state=json_data.getString("State");
b4.setText(type);
b4.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
tr.addView(b4);
tv.addView(tr);

final View vline1 = new View(getApplicationContext());
vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
tv.addView(vline1); // add line below each row 
// tv.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
Log.d("check","here2");
}
}

} catch (Exception e) {
Log.d("in JSon Exception",test);
e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
}
/**
* After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
* **/
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
// dismiss the dialog after getting all products
Log.d("in post","wats the problem");
pDialog.dismiss();
}
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_display_store, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case android.R.id.home:
NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

XML-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backimg" >
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Table" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:shrinkColumns="*"
android:stretchColumns="*" >
</TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
android:text="Access Through OrgID: "
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
android:ems="10" >
<requestFocus />
</EditText>
<Button
android:id="@+id/button1"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
android:text="Go"
android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error Message-

```
11-04 15:48:21.687: E/Trace(695): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-04 15:48:23.498: D/dalvikvm(695): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 40K, 3% free 8013K/8259K, paused 94ms, total 98ms
11-04 15:48:23.530: I/dalvikvm-heap(695): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.625MB for 787816-byte allocation
11-04 15:48:23.857: D/dalvikvm(695): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 8782K/9095K, paused 67ms+191ms, total 332ms
11-04 15:48:23.857: D/dalvikvm(695): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 2ms
11-04 15:48:23.918: D/dalvikvm(695): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 8782K/9095K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
11-04 15:48:23.948: I/dalvikvm-heap(695): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.317MB for 1774384-byte allocation
11-04 15:48:24.148: D/dalvikvm(695): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 10515K/10887K, paused 109ms+28ms, total 203ms
11-04 15:48:24.428: D/dalvikvm(695): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 776K, 11% free 9778K/10887K, paused 66ms, total 68ms
11-04 15:48:24.458: I/dalvikvm-heap(695): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.933MB for 1400016-byte allocation
11-04 15:48:24.678: D/dalvikvm(695): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 10% free 11145K/12295K, paused 111ms+21ms, total 219ms
11-04 15:48:25.450: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:25.568: D/gralloc_goldfish(695): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-04 15:48:31.867: D/dalvikvm(695): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 12K, 9% free 11227K/12295K, paused 39ms, total 42ms
11-04 15:48:31.887: I/dalvikvm-heap(695): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.348MB for 1400016-byte allocation
11-04 15:48:32.067: D/dalvikvm(695): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 9% free 12592K/13703K, paused 79ms+19ms, total 173ms
11-04 15:48:32.308: D/dalvikvm(695): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 2% free 13502K/13703K, paused 46ms, total 48ms
11-04 15:48:32.347: I/dalvikvm-heap(695): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.902MB for 2797584-byte allocation
11-04 15:48:32.537: D/dalvikvm(695): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 2% free 16233K/16455K, paused 105ms+20ms, total 191ms
11-04 15:48:36.737: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 199 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:37.738: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 246 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:38.327: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 129 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:38.517: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:38.677: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:39.217: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:39.658: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:39.917: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 66 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:40.178: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:40.347: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:40.667: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:41.327: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:41.837: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:43.018: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:43.178: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:43.357: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:43.578: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:43.798: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:44.638: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:45.548: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:45.870: D/All Products:(695): [{"ContriID":"100037","Category":"V","Type":"U","Serves":"5","City":"hhhh","State":"jjjg"}]
11-04 15:48:46.179: D/i(695): -1
11-04 15:48:46.368: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:47.418: D/in JSon Exception(695): herehere1here2here4here5after1colheresettext
11-04 15:48:48.058: W/System.err(695): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
11-04 15:48:48.128: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:48.388: W/System.err(695):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4607)
11-04 15:48:48.459: W/System.err(695):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:835)
11-04 15:48:48.518: W/System.err(695):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
11-04 15:48:48.578: W/System.err(695):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
11-04 15:48:48.648: W/System.err(695):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
11-04 15:48:48.698: W/System.err(695):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
11-04 15:48:48.828: W/System.err(695):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:292)
11-04 15:48:48.868: W/System.err(695):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
11-04 15:48:48.938: W/System.err(695):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:292)
11-04 15:48:49.008: W/System.err(695):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:15129)
11-04 15:48:49.248: W/System.err(695):  at android.widget.TableLayout.requestLayout(TableLayout.java:226)
11-04 15:48:49.309: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:49.358: W/System.err(695):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3247)
11-04 15:48:49.448: W/System.err(695):  at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:425)
11-04 15:48:49.579: W/System.err(695):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3225)
11-04 15:48:49.608: W/System.err(695):  at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:416)
11-04 15:48:49.758: W/System.err(695):  at com.example.annapurna.DisplayStore$LoadContri.doInBackground(DisplayStore.java:228)
11-04 15:48:49.848: W/System.err(695):  at com.example.annapurna.DisplayStore$LoadContri.doInBackground(DisplayStore.java:1)
11-04 15:48:49.898: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:48:50.038: W/System.err(695):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-04 15:48:50.098: W/System.err(695):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-04 15:48:50.218: W/System.err(695):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-04 15:48:50.468: W/System.err(695):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-04 15:48:50.499: W/System.err(695):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-04 15:48:50.660: W/System.err(695):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-04 15:48:50.798: W/System.err(695):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-04 15:48:50.968: D/in post(695): wats the problem
11-04 15:48:55.607: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-04 15:51:22.140: I/Choreographer(695): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

I am trying to fetch database entries from a mysql database and displaying it in a table. Php file is working correctly and in logcat it is displaying the data. but not displaying it on UI end and I am not able to find the error, so please help for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Now from your CatLog, you are overloading the UI thread.

It is probable, that while everything is "working", it is loading too much to respond in a timely manor.

What you should do is use a cursor adapter, to load the information from the DB as needed.

You for example may be putting 1000 views onto the screen, when you can only see 5-20 of them?.. Its wasted effort, CPU time, and memory.

This will cause extreme reduction in performance.

Look into custom/ cursor adapters.

p.s. without line indenting, its hard to read the code you posted.

Comment: Currently, as per our database it is retrieving only 2-3 entries but then also it is not able to diaplay them at the UI.